# Что происходит в цикле foreach при передаче циклу не ссылки на коллекцию, а метода, возвращающего коллекцию?

Tags: java, foreach

Выполняется ли метод "values()" при каждой итерации цикла, или же он выполняется всего один раз?

```java
for(String s : values()) {
    //doSmth
}
```

Comment: `values()` вернет ссылку на `Iterable` объект. У него будет вызван метод `iterator()`, который вернет ссылку на `Iterator`. Ну и понеслась - `hasNext()` - `next()` или что там вам надо...

Answer (score 10):

Для того, чтобы показать вам суть, я сделал такой класс. Если вы его запустите, то вы увидите, что выведется строка "x 1"(из метода), и только после нее другие(уже из цикла) - "1","1","1". То есть мы эксперементально доказали, что метод для получении коллекции вызывается только один раз - в начале.

```
static int x=0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(Integer s : returnCollection(x)) {
        System.out.println(s); //выводится в цикле
    }
}
static ArrayList<Integer> returnCollection(int x){
    x++;
    System.out.println("x "+x); // выводится при вызове метода
    ArrayList<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x,x,x));
    return r;
}
```